# Cannot use exports as a type because exports is a value

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I get this error when running `flow check`, but I'm not sure what it means.

> Cannot use exports as a type because exports is a value. To get the type of a value use typeof.

The error location is 0:1 (at the @flow comment). Here's the code:

```
/* @flow */
import Chunk from '../models/Chunk'

export interface IChunkSorter {
  sort(chunks: Chunk[]): Chunk[];
}
```

Any ideas? I've googled for the error message but there's literally no results.

Comment: What is the definition of a `Chunk`? If it is a type, you should import it with `import type ...`. Otherwise define `type ChunkType = typeof Chunk` and use it `sort(chunks: ChunkType[]): ChunkType[];`

Comment: @AlekseyL. `Chunk` is a class and I still get the same error when I use what you suggested :/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem was in a completely different file where I was importing `IChunkSorter` incorrectly. I was using:

```
import type IChunkSorter from './IChunkSorter'
```

This fixed it:

```
import type { IChunkSorter } from './IChunkSorter'
```

Comment: This was the only result! Thanks! 

Comment: Thanks! Mine was because I did `export type` and included an enum. This answer made me realize that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when exporting an `enum` as a type. I fixed the issue by exporting the enum as I would do with a regular constant: `export MyEnum`.