# Error exporting type in Flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I am trying to export a type per the guidelines in the Flow [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/). In global.js I have

```
export type alertConfig = {
  type: string,
  message: string,
  exists: boolean,
};
```

In another file I import and attempt to use this type:

```
import type alertConfig from "./global.js"

type State = {
  alertConf: alertConfig,
  buttonLoading: boolean,
};
```

which gives me the following flow error: `Cannot use object literal as a type because object literal is a value. To get the type of a value use typeof.`

This is strange because when I write `typeof(alertConfig)`, I get the error `Cannot reference type alertConfig [1] from a value position.` So the imported object `alertConfig` is being recognized as a type, but for some reason the original code doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use exports as a type because exports is a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508444/cannot-use-exports-as-a-type-because-exports-is-a-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you exactly why because I'm new to flow as well, but you need to import types with squiggle brackets around them. So your code should be:

```
import type {alertConfig} from "./global.js"
```